# Tabbed sections do not show in github pages

Tags: github, sections, tabbed

I am new at creating content in markdown and using github. I managed to create an html file that included tabbed sections as shown here (https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#tabbed-sections) but as the title says, they do not show at my github page (everything else works just fine). I have been searching in the internet for hours and I was not able to find an answer.